# Register service with multiple lifetime

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, lifetime, ef-core-2.2

In a .Net Core 2.2 application, I need a version of a service as transient and a version as scoped.

For a "regular" service, I could create two different interfaces, register one as transient and one as scoped, but if both need a DbContext, it would mean I'd need to create two DbContext (yes, one can just be a wrapper) and register both, but it *feels* improper.

I'm using dotnet Core's default Dependency Injection framework, which I'm not that familiar with. In UnityIoC, I could easily have done that using named registrations:

```
//Note: Pseudo-code
void Register(IUnityContainer container)
{   
    container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyClass>(
        "Transient",
        new TransientLifetimeManager()
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<MyDbContext>("Transient")));

    container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyClass>(
        "PerResolve",
        new "PerResolve", new PerResolvedLifetimeManager()()
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<MyDbContext>(PerResolve)));

    container.RegisterType<MyDbContext>("Transient", new TransientLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<MyDbContext, MyClass>("PerResolve", new PerResolvedLifetimeManager());
}
```

Bonus points: Using the `IServiceProvider`, how do I ask for the transient resolution vs the scoped resolution?

Comment: I think you may be mistaken about part of your question.  When say:

"...but if both need a DbContext, it would mean I'd need to create two DbContext (yes, one can just be a wrapper) and register both..."

that is not actually correct.  If your DbContext is registered with a scoped lifecycle (which is almost assuredly is), then only a single DbContext will be created for the current scope, and both the scoped and transient versions of MyClass will receive it in their constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this is with two interfaces as shown in the following example:

```
interface IMyScopedInterface
{
    void Foo();
}

interface IMyTransientInterface
{
    void Foo();
}

class MyClass : IMyTransientInterface, IMyScopedInterface
{
    public MyClass(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

and then register your class using the following:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyTransientInterface, MyClass>();
services.AddScoped<IMyScopedInterface, MyClass>();
```

You don't need to do anything special with your `DbContext` in order to support this. Let's walk through how the DI system would resolve these services to see if it can clarify why that's the case.

1. To start, the DI system tries to obtain an instance of `IMyScopedInterface` (typically because the DI system is trying to instantiate some other service whose constructor takes an `IMyScopedInterface` parameter).
2. Because `IMyScopedInterface` has been registered with a scoped lifetime, the DI system first looks within it's collection of services that have already been instantiated for the current scope to see if it has already created an `IMyScopedInterface`. That search comes up empty handed, so the DI system then moves on to create a new instance of `MyClass`.
3. To do that, it examines `MyClass`'s constructor and determines that it needs a `MyDbContext`, so it recurses back through this same flow in order to obtain a `MyDbContext`.
4. The DI system constructs an instance of `MyClass` supplying the obtained `MyDbContext`, and then caches this `MyClass` object as part of the current scope so that subsequent requests for `IMyScopedInterface` within the same scope can receive the shared object.

The same basic flow holds true for `IMyTransientInterface` except that the DI system doesn't bother looking for a previously instantiated instance of the object, and after constructing the new `MyClass` instance it doesn't cache it at all.

What should hopefully be clear from this flow is that it doesn't really matter what the lifetime of `MyDbContext` is.  If it's registered as transient, then every new instance of `MyClass` will get it's own unique instance of `MyDbContext`. If `MyDbContext`'s lifetime is scoped (which is the default behavior in Entity Framework), then all instances of `MyClass` created within a given scope will share a single instance of `MyDbContext` regardless of whether the `MyClass` instances were instantiated for `IMyScopedInterface` or `IMyTransientInterface`.

Comment: I accepted the answer, even though it doesn't answer the question, because it's a good explanation of DI and it can help fellow devs, but in my case, it was simply that I wasn't creating a scope, yet a dependency down the line needed one...